# Disable button on condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, conditional-operator

I'm building a custom pagination component in Angular where you can only press "previous" & "next".

I want to disable the "previous" button whenever the index is equal to 1, and disable the "next" button whenever the index is equal to the last page. Tried some different things i read with ternary operators and ng-if, but i can't get it to work.

This is my pagination component:

```
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="pagination buttons">
  <button mat-icon-button class="vorige-icon" aria-label="vorige icon" (click)="onPrevious()">
    <mat-icon>chevron_left</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>{{this.currentPage + 1}} / {{this.totalPages}}</span>
  <button mat-icon-button class="volgende-icon" aria-label="volgende icon" (click)="onNext()">
    <mat-icon>chevron_right</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

This is the condition:

```
checkDisabled() {
    if (this.currentPage <= 1 || this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
      this.isDisabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you ever use the `isDisabled` value anywhere? Or call `checkDisabled`?

Comment: currently not, i left the conditional statement for clarity but i deleted the non working code. used ng-if & [disabled] but probably had some syntax mistakes

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `[disabled]` attribute for this

```
 <button mat-icon-button class="vorige-icon" aria-label="vorige icon" (click)="onPrevious()"  [disabled]="currentPage <= 1" >
    <mat-icon>chevron_left</mat-icon>
  </button>
 <button mat-icon-button class="volgende-icon" aria-label="volgende icon" (click)="onNext()" [disabled]="currentPage >= totalPages" >
    <mat-icon>chevron_right</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, we directly use the **disabled** property to disable the button.
While in Angular, we need to bind **[disabled]** to native disable property.

Add property onPreviousPage()

```
[disabled]="index === 1"
```

Add property onNextPage()

```
[disabled]="index === lastPage"
```